# Jquery Ajax Request Failing

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

```
var dataParams = "USER=testuser&PASSWORD=testpwd&target=https://mobilesite.com";

    $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',
            url: remoteUrl,
            data: dataParams,
            success: function(data) {   
                console.log(data);                  
            },
            dataType: 'JSON'

        }); // End of Ajax Call
```

I'm attempting to make an JQuery Ajax call to a remote site.  I'm sending a set of parameters to that site and in return I'm supposed to get a JSON formatted response back.  Actually, the call gets to the remote site which returns a 302 then redirects me to another site which in return just stays in "pending" status and kick out the below error message...

"GET https://remoteUrl.com undefined (undefined)"

Any ideas?  Am I missing something?  I've also tried setting async to false, but that just returned an access denied.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Thanks

-Delamatrix

Comment: can we see the contents of dataParams please

Comment: Hi @psynnott.  I've updatd the post with the contents of dataParams.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps remove the URL from `dataParams`? Or are you defining `remoteUrl` earlier?

**Updated:**

```
var dataParams = "USER=testuser&PASSWORD=testpwd";
var remoteUrl = "https://mobilesite.com";

    $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',
            url: remoteUrl,
            data: dataParams,
            success: function(data) {   
                console.log(data);                  
            },
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            crossDomain: true

        }); // End of Ajax Call
```

Comment: Yes, remoteUrl is being defined.  the URL in dataParams is required by the api author, as they take the params and send them to that url.

Comment: Is the URL on a different domain? Try adding crossDomain: true

Comment: Yes, the URL is on a different domain.  No cigar with crossDomain.  I've also tried cache: false.    I tried making this api call with my firefox REST extension, and oddly enough it returns the proper JSON :(.  Go figure.

Comment: Ok try dataType: 'jsonp' and see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain

Comment: Yes Paul, I changed dataType to 'jsonp', but now the ajax call switches to 'GET' instead 'POST'according to the network console tab in chrome....

Comment: I'm at a loss for now, unless you can give more specific details (i.e. the actual site and dummy testing login)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the crossdomain attribute to true (this handles redirection in jQuery 1.5+)?

$.ajax({

```
        type: 'POST',
        url: remoteUrl,
        crossDomain: true,
        data: dataParams,
        success: function(data) {   
            console.log(data);                  
        },
        dataType: 'JSON'

    }); // End of Ajax Call
```

Comment: Yes, i'm using jq 1.5.2, but no luck with the crossdomain attribute.